# Regex with my JQuery function for sql variable name validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to get this to work and I've been googling things for about `45` minutes now.

This is what I'm trying to do.... (note that I am using the replace function, so I guess the regex should be anything but what I want...?)

```
   $('#parameter_name').keyup(function(e){   

      var regex_str = '/@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]/';

      var val       = $(this).val();     

      val           = val.replace(regex_str, ''); 

      $(this).val(val); 
   });
```

And this is what I need the regex to allow:

- first character must be `@`
- second character must be in `[a-zA-Z]`
- there may be 0-many following characters of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

(side note: I realize that `_` may be in the second character position but that gets a little complicated because then it requires there be a third character that is not a `_` and that doesn't fit the rest of the rules I have so... I'm doing the easy thing and just not allowing it)

What ever I put in there.. it ends up leaving whitespace and doing other weird stuff.

**edit:**  so... i've tried a few ways but never found a perfect solution to this

Comment: what can i clarify for you?

Comment: Do you want to do one or possibly more replacement(s) ?

Comment: Is this validation happening on the client side? If so you are also validating it on the back end right? In-browser validation is a nice convenience feature to provide, but never trust anything given to you by the user especially if you will be putting it in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your written specification, you seem to need

```
/^@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*/
```

The `^` matches the start of the string so that you can't have something before.

If what you want is to match possibly more than one occurrence in a string, then you probably need to test for word boundaries and add the `g` flag :

```
/\b@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b/g
```

Note also that the regex isn't a string, it's a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), you must remove the `'` : it's

```
val.replace(/\b@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b/g, '');
```

instead of

```
val.replace('/\b@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b/g', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
'/@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/'
```

@ character, followed by exactly one letter, followed by zero or more letters, numbers, and underscores.